# Cast object to parent

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting, parent

I have a problem with inheritance in C++. Here is what I would like to do:

```
class parent
{
   public:
   int a;
};

class son : public parent
{
   public:
   int b;
   operator parent()
   {
      parent p; p.a = a + b;
      return p;
   }
}


void funct(parent a)
{
    cout<<a.a;
}

son s; s.a = 3; s.b = 4;
funct(s);
```

And I would like it to print out 7. Instead, the casting is implicitly done without affecting anything, and 3 is printed out. Could anyone give me an advice on how to do this? Is this even possible?

Comment: Why not use `struct` if all members are `public`?

Comment: A `son` is a `parent`, thus your cast operator is never called.

Comment: If you use `protected` or `private` inheritance, things might change.

Comment: I would try virtual functions
PS. protected or private inheritance will not help

Comment: @Deduplicator thanks for the hint but it does not work. It says "parent is an inaccessible base of son"..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the C++ Standard

> A conversion function **is never used to convert** a (possibly
>   cv-qualified) object to the (possibly cv-qualified) same object type
>   (or a reference to it), **to a (possibly cv-qualified) base class** of
>   that type (or a reference to it), or to (possibly cv-qualified) void.

You could use a virtual function that outputs data members or you could define operator << as pseudo-virtual (that is that calls a virtual function) for the classes.

For example

```
class parent
{
   public:
   virtual std::ostream & out( std::ostream &os ) const { return os << a; }
   int a;
};

class son : public parent
{
   public:
   int b;
   std::ostream & out( std::ostream &os ) const { return os << a + b; }
};

std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &os, const parent &obj )
{
   return obj.out( os );
}
```

Comment: @Deduplicator But I think he does not want to write each function as two functions that has a parameter of type parent &.

Comment: I'm sure you are right, which is why I already upvoted. Just mentioning it for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

This is how 7 will be printed:

```
funct(s.operator parent());
```

And one point to remember:

`funct(s)` //would result in object slicing as the 'funct' takes base class object by value.

Answer (score 0):

Object is automatically casting to parent class by method like this:

```
operator base_type&() {return (base_type&)*this;}
```

You can't change this method.

You can only change inheritance to protected or private. The compiler never do a implicit casting then, even if you define casting operator.

You can only write a ordinary method which can do that casting and call it, when you need.